# poner los valores de los campos seleccionados a null

Tags: c#, jquery, html

Estoy en un proyecto en mvc tengo lo siguiente.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selecctall").change(function () {
        $(".checkbox1").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
</script>

<table style=" font-size:20px" align="center" class="table-striped, text-center, table-condensed" cellpadding="20">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-center" style="color:#e98300;font-family:'Trebuchet MS'">
            <th class="text-center" ; bgcolor="black"><input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" value="All" id="selecctall" /></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
foreach(filtro de la busqueda)
{
    <tbody>
       <tr style="color:white ;font-family:'Trebuchet MS'">
           <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="sid" class="checkbox1" /></td>
       </tr>
}
<input name="posponer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="posponer" style=" color:white" title="Operar" />
```

Al final de las tabla tengo un botón, y necesito que coja todos los `checkbox` que están marcados y vaya al controlador para poder operar con ellos.

Comment: Y desde los quieres poner a null? desde jquery o desde c#?

Comment: desde c# necesito que coger todos los que están marcados y llevarlos a un Action result para alli poner el campo que quiero en null

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer uso de jquery para tomar los check marcados y enviar la lista al action haciendo uso de `$.ajax`. Lo que no veo es donde defines el `value` indicando el valor que enviaras al action.

Si defines

```
foreach(var item in <filtro>)
{
    <tbody>
       <tr style="color:white ;font-family:'Trebuchet MS'">
           <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="sid" class="checkbox1" value="@item.Id" /></td>
       </tr>
}
```

veras somo se usa el `@item.Id` para asignarle un valor, entonces tomarias la lista y la envias al action

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        $('form').submit(function(){
            e.preventDefault();

            var params = {
               selection = []
            };

            $(".checkbox1:checked").foreach(function(){
                params.selection.push($(this).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("NombreCtrl", "NombreAction")',
                data: params,
                success: function (data) {
                    //aqui codigo
                }
            });

        });
    })

</script>
```

El action en el controler seria

```
public class xxController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult xxAction(List<string> selection)
    {
        //codigo
    }
}
```

la idea es que el valor del parametro coincida con el del params que defiens en javascript